# State of Object variables and arrays after an activity is finished

Tags: android

Why does the values of the variables or arrays belonging to an object remain the same when the activity from which the object is called is destroyed? Shouldn't the object along with its variables and their values also be destroyed? If the same object is called from an other activity which inherits the former activity, the values of the variables are the same. They wont change. Why is this so?

Comment: A question hard to understand. Show an example of Situation you area asking!

Comment: Consider a quizz app. All the questions have the same format. All of them inherit similar properties from the first question. And also, all the questions are displayed in their own activities. Now after answering the first question, that object along with its variables and values must get destroyed and then to view the second question another object must be created. But the problem is, the variables and arrays of this object retain the same values  of the previous object's variables'. Why is this so?

Comment: Your activity was just may be paused and not destroyed. to be sure that it should be destroyed call the method `finish()` just after you leave the activity and it will be removed from backstack as well.

Comment: Can you explain to me in more detail? or suggest some resources? Would be very helpful..